# database integration and report generator

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, data-binding, report

I have this situation, maybe it is too basic for this site, but I still hope to get some suggestions:

- There are 3 different systems that I need to collect data from, all 3 on different servers in a local network. One of them is based on MySQL database which I have complete access to, the second one is based on MS Access database, and the third one has a flat file database and its data can only be accessed through txt exports from application
- I need to collect data into independent database and create excel and pdf reports
- I don't need charts, nicely formatted excel table should be just fine
- Data is updated each hour, so it should be collected and the report should be produced every hour

  1. Any suggestions about how to integrate the data, which dbms is best to use for this purpose?
  2. What is the best option for creating excel and pdf reports without having to buy any software?

I hope to get some guidelines, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well something to look into for Excel is the Microsoft Interop libraries.  It's free and integrates directly into Office tools.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx

As far as your database situation, is there any problem with just coding the server calls and statements into different classes, then setting it on a one hour timer to refresh and collect new data?